# Tokenizing a string with strtok() causes crash in c

Tags: c, string, segmentation-fault, tokenize, strtok

Im trying to create a function that tokenizes a given string with given delimeters, puts the tokens in a 2D char array and returns it. Below the code is displayed:

```
char** stringTokenizer(const char* str, const char* delims){
       char** tokens;
       size_t len = strlen(str);
       char localstr[len+1];
       int tokenslen=0;
       strcpy(localstr, str);
       tokens=malloc(sizeof(char*));

       char* tmp = strtok(localstr, delims);
       while(tmp){
                  if(++tokenslen>1) realloc(tokens, tokenslen*sizeof(char*));
                  tokens[tokenslen-1]=malloc((strlen(tmp)+1)*sizeof(char));
                  strcpy(tokens[tokenslen-1],tmp);
                  tmp = strtok(NULL, delims);
       }
       if(tokenslen==0){
                        free(tokens);
                        return NULL;

       } else return tokens;
}
```

When i try printing any of tokens[i] im getting a crash.

As long there is a token I increment the size of the tokens array and allocate the pointer for the token to be copied.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: you should consider double pointer over here: `tokens=malloc(sizeof(char*));` atleast.

Comment: How are you printing the tokens?

Comment: `realloc(tokens, tokenslen*sizeof(char*));` : you drop return value.

Comment: i print them like this puts(tokens[i])

Comment: @BLUEPIXY what do you exactly mean?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: I think you should post that as the answer

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/realloc/ You need to capture the return value from realloc into a variable. Realloc may change the address that tokens is pointing to

Comment: @ChrisKon ; realloc is not guaranteed to extend the memory remains of the original address.

Comment: oh... thanks @BLUEPIXY i thought once realloc was void it would not return anything. thanks and sry for the silly question!

Comment: should i delete the question?

Comment: I would leave it open, I know I learned something from it

Comment: Best thing would be for @BLUEPIXY to post it as an answer, so you can mark the question as answered.

Comment: @Varun: do not edit questions to provide answers. There's an answer section for that. I rolled back your edit (the reviewers that approved it were a little trigger happy I guess).

Comment: @netcoder: I rejected the edit and was monitoring it to see if it got approved. To my dismay it did get approved. Thank you for rolling back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing this

```
char** stringTokenizer(const char* str, const char* delims){
       char** tokens = NULL;
       size_t len = strlen(str);
       char localstr[len+1];
       int tokenslen=0;
    char **temp;//Change
       strcpy(localstr, str);

       //tokens=malloc(sizeof(char*));

       char* tmp = strtok(localstr, delims);
       while(tmp){
                  //if(++tokenslen>1) realloc(tokens, tokenslen*sizeof(char*));
    temp = realloc(tokens, tokenslen*sizeof(char*));
    tokens = temp;
                  tokens[tokenslen-1]=malloc((strlen(tmp)+1)*sizeof(char));
                  strcpy(tokens[tokenslen-1],tmp);
                  tmp = strtok(NULL, delims);
       }
       /*if(tokenslen==0){
                        free(tokens);
                        return NULL;

       } else*/ return tokens;
}
```

Thank you @netcoder